# Showing that a nonvertical line is an abstract geometry

Tags: geometry

A vertical line is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $L_a = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | x = a\}$. A non-vertical line is any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the form $L_{m,b} = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 | y = mx+b\}$. Prove that $L_a$ and $L_{m,b}$ are abstract geometry.

The definition of an abstract geometry consists of a set $Y$, whose elements are called points, together with a collection $L$ of nonempty subsets of $Y$, called lines such that for every two points $A,B \in Y$ there is a line $l \in L$ with $A \in L$ and $B \in L$. And every line has at least two points.

---

I know how to prove $L_a$, by letting $P$ and $Q$ be points where $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ thus letting $a=x_1=x_2$ then both $P$ and $Q$ belong to $L_a$. However, for non-vertical lines, $L_{m,b}$, I am a bit confused. If I let $P=(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ where $x_1 \neq x_2$ then $y_1=mx_1 + b$ and $y_2=mx_2 + b$ how can I show that both those points lie within the same line?

Comment: Your definition is confusing. Is $Y$ a set that contains itself? Should $X,Y$ be in $L$ or $l$? You may want to clean up the notation in order for this question to make any sense.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 I have cleaned it up. Sorry didn't realize i used Y twice .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be confused about exactly what you're asking. The sets $L_a$ and $L_{m,b}$ for a particular $a$ or $(m,b)$ are just individual sets of points. If you consider the pair $(L_a,\{L_a\})$, or similarly with $L_{m,b}$, it is trivially a geometry. However, this is not special; consider any set $Y$ with $|Y|>1$. Then, $(Y,\{Y\})$ is a geometry $-$ you can verify this with the definition.

If you consider $(\mathbb{R}^2,L_a)$ or $(\mathbb{R}^2,L_{m,b})$, neither of them are abstract geometries. For the first, simply choose $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$, a pair of points from $\mathbb{R}^2$ which don't lie on any $L_a$. For the second, choose $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$, a pair of points from $\mathbb{R}^2$ which don't lie on any $L_{m,b}$.

However, if you consider the set $L_E$ of all vertical and non-vertical lines, so that $L_a, L_{m,b} \in L_E$ for all $a,m,b$, then $(\mathbb{R}^2,L_E)$ is an abstract geometry. To show this, first note that each of $L_a$ and $L_{m,b}$ contain more than one point. Then, pick any pair of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, say $p_1 = (x_1,y_1)$ and $p_2 = (x_2,y_2)$. If $x_1=x_2$, we have $p_1,p_2 \in L_{x_1} \in L_E$. Otherwise, $x_1\neq x_2$. In this case, we choose $m =\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ and $b = y_1-mx_1$. Then, $p_1,p_2 \in L_{m,b} \in L_E$ (you can verify this by showing that $y_1 = mx_1+b$ and $y_2 = mx_2+b$), so that $(\mathbb{R}^2,L_E)$ is in fact an abstract geometry.

Comment: Hmm can you elaborate why letting $m =\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$ and $b = y_1-mx_1$ implies that $p_1,p_2 \in L_{m,b} \in L_E$.

Comment: If $(x_1,y_1)\in L_{m,b}$, then we must have $y_1 = mx_1 + b$. Similarly, we need $y_2 = mx_2+b$. Since the $m$ and $b$ need to be the same for both of these, we can treat it as an algebraic system. Subtracting the two equations eliminates $b$ so you can solve for $m$. Then you can solve either of the two equations for $b$ easily.